# Convert params args to a lambda expression in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, parameters, where-clause

I am looking to take the params string[] args and convert it to a lambda expression for Entity Framework.

Something like this...

```
public main(params string[] args)
{
    DataContext context = new DataContext();

    foreach(string arg in args)
    {
        //build Query
    }

    context.Things.Where(/*Query*/);
}
```

Comment: where what? a `thing` contains any of the supplied strings?  You have to add more information

Comment: What kind of EntityFramework expression? What have you tried so far? Please provide at least a [mcve].

Comment: This should be a fairly simple thing to do. It deals with Expression.Parameter and Expression.Property etc.  I'm just looking for an implementation of this.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Where is the query or filter.  A Thin comes from a DataContext as a Model.  The point is that args may contain a variety of attributes of a Thing that may be queried on.  So, in this case the attributes of Thing mean nothing.

Comment: you could use DynamicLinq expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic linq to create string based expressions.
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

The downside is that these expression are evaluated at runtime, so you won't be able to catch errors at compile time.

Or you can use Expression trees to construct expressions .
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637(v=vs.110).aspx

This will be a bit more code, but you will get the advantage of compile time type checks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll review these.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent article is here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically

Here is my solution:

```
public static Expression<Func<TClass, bool>> ConvertParamArgsToExpression<TClass>(string[] args)
{
    Expression finalExpression = Expression.Constant(true);

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TClass), "x");

    foreach (string arg in args) {
        string[] values = arg.Split('=');
        PropertyInfo prop = typeof(TClass).GetProperty(values[0]);
        if(prop != null)
        {
            Expression expression = null;
            var member = Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name);
            var constant = Expression.Constant(values[1]);

            expression = Expression.Equal(member, constant);

            finalExpression = Expression.AndAlso(finalExpression, expression);
        }
    }

    return (Expression.Lambda<Func<TClass, bool>>(finalExpression, parameter));
}
```

Usage:

```
    Expression<Func<AdminPageObject, bool>> expression = LambdaConverter.ConvertParamArgsToExpression<AdminPageObject>(args);
    if(expression != null)
    {
        items = items.Where(expression);
    }
```